# Send image using Android cloud to device messaging framework

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-c2dm

Hey folks, I am wondering whether android allows to build apps that can send images to cloud that are more than 1KB in size. My concern was regarding a para they have mentioned in their documentation - [Android Cloud to device Messaging Framework documentation](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#limitations)

> Blockquote
>   Limitations
>   C2DM imposes the following limitations:
>   The message size limit is 1024 bytes.
>   Google limits the number of messages a sender sends in aggregate, and the number of messages a sender sends to a specific device

If yes, how and where to find a proper documentation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C2DM isn't about sending data from a device to cloud (that would be D2CM), it's meant to allow your 'server' to send data to Google's C2DM servers which then forward that data to a registered device (or devices).

Although (technically) a mobile device could act as an originating 'server' which sends data to the Google C2DM servers intended for another mobile device, this isn't what its designed for.

The limit on message size is for practical reasons (reducing traffic) and 1024 bytes should be enough to send a notification. If more data is to be transferred the message can perhaps include a URI that a mobile app can use to take further action.

**EDIT** In response to your comment...

I have no experience of either AWS or Google app engine - you'll need to study their SDKs and tutorials.

The point about the 'cloud' is that resources (servers / services etc) are accessible from anywhere through URIs/URLs which can be looked up using DNS (for example).

Mobile devices are a different concept and C2DM is meant to be a lightweight way of informing a device that there is a new image (for example) available. The device itself is responsible for downloading that image. As for uploading images, again the device should know how to find the 'cloud' server/service and performing the upload itself using HTTP/FTP or whatever transfer protocol supported by both ends.

Comment: Could you suggest a way so that I can send and receive images from android app to remote service(say amazon web service) or Google app engine?

Comment: @prap19: See my EDIT in my answer.